# É possível passar um formgroup para o componente pai?

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho um componente pai e um componente filho, eu preciso passar o formgroup do componente filho para o componente pai, eu tentei dessa forma:

**Elemento filho:**

```
@Output() formGroup = new EventEmitter<Categoria>();
```

No constructor eu faço uma instancia desse form group:

```
constructor() {this.formGroup = createFormGroup()}

let createFormGroup = (dataItem?: CategoriaIcone) => {
    if (dataItem) {
        return new FormGroup({
        'NomeImagem': new FormControl(dataItem.NomeImagem), //nome da imagem
        'UrlImagemIcone': new FormControl(dataItem.UrlImagemIcone),
        'Imagem': new FormControl(''),
        'TypeImage': new FormControl('')
        });
    } else {
        return new FormGroup({
        'NomeImagem': new FormControl(''),
        'UrlImagemIcone': new FormControl(''),
        'Imagem': new FormControl(''),
        'TypeImage': new FormControl('')
        });
    }
}
```

Porém eu recebo no constructor:

> Type 'FormGroup' is missing the following properties from type
>   'EventEmitter': __isAsync, emit, subscribe, observers, and
>   17 more.

Comment: Voce criou ele como eventEmitter e depois reasignou ele a um formgroup, por isso o erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nesse caso parece melhor usar o viewChild.

```
@ViewChild('child') childComponent: childComponent;


submitForm(){
   console.log(childComponent.form);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A comunicação entre componentes pode ser feita tanto pai para o filho como o inverso. Porém, pelo que entendi do seu problema, a solução adequada é através ViewChild.

Porém lembrando a arquitetura de componentes analise se realmente precisa dos campos do formulário no componente pai ou se precisa apenas dos valores dos campos. A ideia desse pensamento é garantir o princípio da única responsabilidade. O pai não precisa obter de fato o FormGroup, mas o form value.

Se ainda precisar desses valores apenas quando realizar submit através de um botão é recomendado usar o @Output.

Para ambos os casos deixo um artigo para estudo da troca de dados entre componentes: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/